# how to order the cypher result by the default id of the nodes?

Tags: neo4j, sql-order-by, cypher

I wanna oder the result by the default Node id 
this is an example :

start n=node:nodeINDEX("TYPE:城市")
return n
order by ???????

the expected return : node【0】 ，node【1】 node【2】

Answer (score 7):

ID is a special case, it's not a property but a function on a node:

```
start n=node:nodeINDEX("TYPE:城市") return n order by id(n);
```